# Enviar parámetros tipo Lista por AJAX a un controller en MVC 5

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc

tengo esta funcion:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type:"post", 
    url:"/Home2/test01", 
    data: procesoData,
    succes: function(datos){ 
        $("#DatosRespuesta").html(datos); 
    }
);
```

donde procesoData corresponde a una lista de datos:

```
var procesoData = { 'items':[ ] }
```

**Mi pregunta es** 
¿Cómo puedo trabajar con ellos (recibir el parámetro en forma de lista) en un controller de  MVC 5 en C#? Cualquier ayuda me vendría bien, gracias.

*[Pregunta formulada originalmente en Google+](https://plus.google.com/u/0/113353555662318974769/posts/ZQ5CR7ya8wb)*

Comment: Podría responder yo mismo la pregunta pero esa no es la idea, queremos mostrar a las nuevas generaciones que pueden encontrar en SOes una fuente inagotable de respuestas a sus preguntas.

Comment: `procesoData` no es una "lista", es un objeto con un campo llamado `items` que es un array

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz `procesoData` es un objeto el cual una de sus propiedades es un *array* y sí puede ser recibido como tal en el *controller*

Comment: @Equiso quise decir propiedad en lugar de campo, pero a parte de eso es lo mismo que he mencionado, nunca dije que no se podía recibir con parámetro del *Action*

Comment: @MatthewJoelRodríguezLlanos Muy aparte de ese tema tienes dos errores JavaScript en tu código: `success` es con doble "s" al final y la última línea debe terminar en `});`

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz gracias sólo quise ser fiel al código javascript original, y en cuanto al ; JS puede vivir sin él.

Comment: @MatthewJoelRodríguezLlanos el problema no es el `;`sino el `}` faltante

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz oh, mil perdones, se me ha escapado, lo dejaré así a ver quien más está tan atento, muchas gracias nuevamente.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33148/discussion-between-matthew-joel-rodriguez-llanos-and-carlos-munoz).

Comment: Si la pregunta original fue publicada en otro sitio, estaría bien que incluyeras un enlace a la misma. Y de paso, invita al autor de la pregunta original a pasarse por aquí y unirse a nosotros. :-)

Comment: Ya he invitado al autor (y el resto de la comu) a visitar la pregunta, enseguida añado el link, gracias.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

MVC realiza el *binding* de acuerdo a los nombres de los parámetros y el tipo, entonces para recibir los elementos de un array según el ejemplo en tu *controller* Home2:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test01(List</* tipo de los elementos */> items) {
    var resultado = // Los datos que quieres devolver

    return Json(resultado);
}
```

Aquí depende el tipo de elementos que hay en `items`, en el caso más simple si fuese un conjunto de cadenas usuarías `List<string>`.

Probablemente estés envíando objetos con más propiedades, en ese caso tendrías que crear una clase en C# que siga la estructura de los objetos de JavaScript para que MVC los deserialize en esta.  Por ejemplo si en el lado cliente tienes

```
var procesoData = { 'items': [ 
    { nombre: 'uno', edad: 1 }, 
    { nombre: 'dos', edad: 2 }, 
    { nombre: 'tres', edad: 3 }
] };
```

Entonces en C# podrías crear una clase

```
public class Usuario
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public int Edad { get; set; }
}
```

y en la firma del *action* usar `List<Usuario> items`

---

Por otro lado, si el objeto que se está envíando tiene más propiedades que solamente `items` ya sería recomendable crear un modelo específico para recibir todo

```
public class ProcesoData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    public List<Usuario> Items { get; set; }
}
```

los datos igualmente serían mapeados de manera automática por el nombre de las propiedades y usarías este modelo

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test01(ProcesoData data)
```

Comment: podrías por favor aclarar si se pueden usar parámetros del tipo dynamic y cómo sería su implementación (un ejemplito), gracias.